# Create a mime file on Mac

Tags: firefox, mime

I'm sorry to bother you but I'm going crazy.

I'm a simple Mac user and absolutely not a coding master. At all... I try to open markdown files in Firefox but it doesn't work. I understand it's not possible any more and I have to check the setting in `about:config`but of course, the mime file isn't there. So I tried to create it... but it's definitely harder than expected. I think this step is so easy for you than nobody take the time to explain how to do step by step. It should take 2 min and I'm trying for hours now.

It would be great if someone could explain that simply.

Thanks a lot
Tschüss
GG

Comment: Markdown files are just directly editable plaintext - were you using a browser-extension that made HTML views of Markdown files, perhaps? To my knowledge Firefox has never supported it as a built-in feature.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mime file" - do you mean setting a macOS "MIME" `Content-Type` or file-extension association so that `.md` files open in Firefox?

Comment: Yes at the end I would like to use an add on called Markdown Viewer. You can change a lot of graphic thing, use mermaid, print, etc.

But it doesn't work because on "MIME" in this case. For me, it's the weird part.

Comment: I think you just need to edit the `MimeTypes.rdf` file in your Firefox profile: http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf

Comment: I'm not sure to have it... Sorry !

I found this > handlers.json (mimeTypes.rdf in Firefox 54 and below; bug 1287658)

Comment: And I found this line in it `"text/markdown":{"action":0,"ask":false,"handlers":[{"name":"Firefox","path":"/Applications/Firefox.app"}],"extensions":["md"]}` But I'm not sure it's usefull.